# How to mirror an NTFS directory structure in Rsync

Tags: linux, windows, rsync

Being a Linux tool I'm not sure if this is supported but is it possible to mirror an NTFS file system in it's entirety, including all symlinks?  The symlinks must be copied and point to their **new** destination.  For example imagine:

```
C:\Users\USER_HERE\AppData\Local\Application Data -> C:\Users\USER_HERE\AppData\Local\
```

I want the copy to be

```
D:\Users\USER_HERE\AppData\Local\Application Data -> D:\Users\USER_HERE\AppData\Local\
instead of 
D:\Users\USER_HERE\AppData\Local\Application Data -> C:\Users\USER_HERE\AppData\Local\
```

Comment: what about using robocopy? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Comment: robocopy has issues

Comment: And you think those robocopy issues are what?  I have yet to find a rsync port for Windows that doesn't suck.  Every rsync port I have found is buggy in some important way.